# When accessing the bounds of an Area from an ArrayList<Area> outside of the class it was initiated in, the Rectangle received is incorrect

Tags: java, arraylist, awt, area, bounds

I have worked through this code a number of times but cannot seem to understand it's behaviour.

I add a number of instances of `Area` to an `ArrayList` in a for loop, whilst also creating another `Area` which is an amalgamation of all those added to the array (however this amalgamated `Area` is never added to the `ArrayList`).

When trying to retrieve the first item of the `ArrayList` from another class it gives me the bounds of the amalgamated `Area` which had never been added in the first place?!?!

```
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CorruptArray {
public ArrayList<Area> arrayList = new ArrayList<Area>();

public CorruptArray(){
        double x = 100.0;
        double y = 200.0;
        double width = 100.0;
        double height = 200.0;
        Area map = null;

        int i = 5;
        for(int j =0 ; j<i; j++){
            arrayList.add(new Area(new Rectangle2D.Double(x,y,width,height)));

            x+=10;
            y+=10;
            width+=10;
            height+=10;
        }

        int k = 0;
        for(Area area : arrayList){
            System.out.println("INITIAL BOUNDS ON ENTRY:  " + area.getBounds().toString());
            if(k == 0){
                map = area;
                k++;

            }else{
                map.add(area);

            }
            System.out.println("OVERALL JOINED AREA - map   " + map.getBounds().toString() + "\n");
        }

        TestArray test = new TestArray(this);
    }

private static class TestArray{
    TestArray(CorruptArray ca){
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        for(Area area : ca.arrayList){
            System.out.println("RETRIVAL OF BOUNDS FROM TestArray:  " + area.getBounds().toString());
        }
    }
}



public static void main(String args[]){
    new CorruptArray();
}
```

When running the programme this is the output I get:

```
INITIAL BOUNDS ON ENTRY:  java.awt.Rectangle[x=100,y=200,width=100,height=200]
OVERALL JOINED AREA - map java.awt.Rectangle[x=100,y=200,width=100,height=200]

INITIAL BOUNDS ON ENTRY:  java.awt.Rectangle[x=110,y=210,width=110,height=210]
OVERALL JOINED AREA - map java.awt.Rectangle[x=100,y=200,width=120,height=220]

INITIAL BOUNDS ON ENTRY:  java.awt.Rectangle[x=120,y=220,width=120,height=220]
OVERALL JOINED AREA - map java.awt.Rectangle[x=100,y=200,width=140,height=240]

INITIAL BOUNDS ON ENTRY:  java.awt.Rectangle[x=130,y=230,width=130,height=230]
OVERALL JOINED AREA - map java.awt.Rectangle[x=100,y=200,width=160,height=260]

INITIAL BOUNDS ON ENTRY:  java.awt.Rectangle[x=140,y=240,width=140,height=240]
OVERALL JOINED AREA - map java.awt.Rectangle[x=100,y=200,width=180,height=280]




RETRIVAL OF BOUNDS FROM TestArray:  java.awt.Rectangle[x=100,y=200,width=180,height=280]
RETRIVAL OF BOUNDS FROM TestArray:  java.awt.Rectangle[x=110,y=210,width=110,height=210]
RETRIVAL OF BOUNDS FROM TestArray:  java.awt.Rectangle[x=120,y=220,width=120,height=220]
RETRIVAL OF BOUNDS FROM TestArray:  java.awt.Rectangle[x=130,y=230,width=130,height=230]
RETRIVAL OF BOUNDS FROM TestArray:  java.awt.Rectangle[x=140,y=240,width=140,height=240]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't add the amalgamated area, but you take the first area from the arraylist and modify it. It happens exactly here:

```
if (k == 0) {
   map = area;
```

Later your add the other areas from the list to the map - which is the first area on the list. You may want to create a *new* area based on the first one from the list instead:

```
if (k == 0) {
   map = new Area(area);
```

Comment: I thought that would only be a problem if I stated `area = map`and even then why should my subsequent adjustments to map effect the first area in the `ArrayList` if I've moved on to the other items in the list?

Comment: You've copied the *reference* of the first `area` object to the `map` variable. A single instance of `Area` is now referenced by `map` and the first entry in the list (`arraylist.get(0)`) and `map.getBounds()` and `arraylist.getBounds()` get the bounds from the  same area.